# Laptop keyboard behaves weirdly after water damage. Is there a way to repair it?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, repair, water-damage

I spilled some hot water on my laptop keyboard about a year ago and as you all guessed, it partly stopped working (i.e. some keys weren't working at all and some keys were acting as if they were other keys [as well]). I put the laptop on the radiator for the night and it helped to revive some keys, but not all.
Luckily, not too many important keys were damaged, so I used a software called PowerToys to remap my keyboard and I'm using it this way ever since.

Now the weird part. About a month ago, some keys randomly changed their behavior and they are either not working since or working as different keys, some keys even behave as multiple keys at once.

Since this random change occurred, is there any chance to repair my keyboard?

Comment: Unlikely to be repairable, sounds like long term corrosion damage. You should have put your laptop in a large bag of rice for several days when it first happened. The rice absorbs all the water.

Comment: I wouldn't advocate the radiator or rice. First thing to do is not hope & pray it will get better all on its own, it's to immediately disconnect the battery, then strip it down & dry what you can. Use contact cleaner in difficult areas to try dispel water. Whatever the initial short doesn't kill, later corrosion will.

Comment: Replace the keyboard

Comment: Alright y'all, thanks for the tips. I was really hoping it'll get better over time (i.e. dry by itself) but it seems like that's not the case, so I'm replacing it.

Comment: Also, random fun fact: there was a day when _all the keys_ were working correctly out of the blue :D The next day (almost) everything went wrong again like nothing happened, though.